# Error with file upload when file size is more than 100 mb with php?

Tags: php, filesize

I have a file upload page in php. It is giving a file error.
When I echo out `$file_error`, it returns 1(The uploaded file exceeds the `upload_max_filesize` directive in `php.ini`).
My upload file size is 120Mb.
I have set `upload_max_filesize`=`1000M` in php.ini.
I have also set `post_max_size` = `1000M`.

But when I upload a file of size less than 100Mb, it is uploaded without any problem.

What could be the issue in this?

Comment: What `echo ini_get('upload_max_filesize'), ", " , ini_get('post_max_size')` gives you?

Comment: Is it Apache? Did you restart the server after changing php.ini?

Comment: it gives 100M,1000M. Yes I did restart Apache

Comment: It means that `upload_max_filesize` isn't set to 1000M, or set incorrectly and rolled back to standard value of 100M. Try setting it to 200M, restart apache, see what happens

Comment: Still giving 100M,1000M

Comment: Please show the php.ini lines how you changed them

Comment: r u at shared hosting environment?

Comment: what is the `memory_limit` set to, btw? it should be higher than those two

Comment: Here are the php.ini lines:
; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.

; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize

`upload_max_filesize=1000M`

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.

; http://php.net/upload-max-filesize
`post_max_size=10000M`

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)

; http://php.net/memory-limit

`memory_limit=1024M`

Comment: @fortune: No. It is a dedicated environment. Just hosting one local upload page.

Comment: r u making changes at the correct ini file? you will get path of your ini file by writing a script with content <?php phpinfo(); ?> //Loaded configuration file

Comment: Yes, it's the same file that I am changing.